# Scroll when linked to id on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Note: I'm new to webdev and i'm building this site with bootstrap

I'm building a one page site and the navbar at the top directs the user to the relevant id. the problem i'm having is that i want it to scroll to the id when clicked (see http://www.blastprocessor.co.uk/). I also want to set the class as active when the user scrolls past a specific id.

I have no idea where to start but i'll post my html code here.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="34">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" id="main-menu">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#whatissm">What We Are</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#whyusesm">Why Us</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#whatdoessmeoffer">What We Offer</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
<li><a href="#">Right Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, this is all done through JavaScript (Jquery, since you got bootstrap already running)

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element) to scroll and animate to your ID.

To add your class after scrolling past your ID use:

```
//assign the window and all the contents into variables
//instead of going and grabbing it from the DOM on every scroll

var $window = $(window),
    $content = $('.content');

$window.scroll(function () {
    $content.each(function () {
        //for each element that has a class of content
        //check its position and add SomeClass
        if ($window.scrollTop() >= $(this).position().top) {
            $(this).addClass('SomeClass');
        } else if ($window.scrollTop() <= $(this).position().top) {
            //if window position is less then remove it
            $(this).removeClass('SomeClass');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome!!!!! At the moment I want to make the scroll to stop 50px above the id, is there any way to do that?

Comment: using your new code, not getting it to work. i made $target1 = $('#whyusesm'); and $target2 = $('#whybutton'); as the id for the <button> is whybutton and the id for the relevant h1 is whyusesm... just wanted to use that to test but its not making the class active...

Comment: What do you mean one active class? Can you give me more details

Comment: only the first section is highlighted yellow.... none of the others are... so as you scroll it doesn't update it as you scroll down.... i was thinking of fixing this with another variable $activescroll but haven't been able to solve it yet.

Comment: @RobertCrous I have updated the answer to do this. See here http://jsfiddle.net/stvs730h/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to make your scroll animation. Regarding adding a class 'active' to the past id actually you can follow the answer of @ahb. For your need i just added a var `reduce` in the function which will help you reduce `50px` from the actuall offset.

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  var reduce = 50;
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - reduce
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[ORIGINAL SOURCE](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

[DEMO](http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/)

Comment: im using this code for scrolling:

    $(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    $('[title]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
    );
    $('a').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) +     '"]').offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
    });

Comment: just for future reference: remove the px from the reduce variable and it works like a charm! Thank you so so so much!!!!

Comment: Sorry thats ma bad didn't do with any intention never checked that will edit it

Comment: since you seem to be a bit more active, can you help me with ahb's code? either i'm not implementing it correctly or it's just not working